# Displaying the correct download forms across multiple pages based on users selections

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am attempting to make a 4 page system that has a user complete each pages step in order to progress further until they finally checkout. In the first step/page i collect the users choices e.g. what camp they want to attend along with some info about the attendee. This gets stored in a database then the user is redirected to step/page 2 where they are presented the correct  release forms to download based on their choices. However I am trying to figure out how I can recall their individual choice when I've switched pages. I know I can recall their choices by their saved database information but am unsure how to display the correct users choice to show them the correct forms. I'm not having anybody log in so I can't recall the user that way.

I'm thinking I'll have to store the users data some other way that I am not thinking of in order to recall which forms to present them on the next page and so forth as step/page 3 has more forms and step/page 4 gives them their camps price and checkout.

Just to clarify why i don't stay on the same page. Originally I had all 4 steps on the same page but customers were skipping steps saying they missed them or some other excuse, I figure a 4 page step by step would fore the customers not to skip anything.

Thanks for any conversations and thoughts!

Comment: See [Session Handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: ^^ this. store the data in the user's session instead of the database. Unless you add some type of login/authentication system, it will be tricky to persist it anywhere else.

Comment: "customers were skipping steps saying they missed them or some other excuse"...yeah ok but that's what validation checks are for, to ensure all the required fields are completed, and the data generally makes business sense. You still need the same checks now you've got separate steps. Otherwise you can't "force" users to do anything. But still it's often a nicer UI to break it down into smaller portions (although you could arguably just use JavaScript to show and hide different parts of the form, instead of having totally separate pages, which usually results in a smoother user experience).

Comment: ^ Yup, JavaScript show/hide plus ajax would probably be a "cleaner" user experience.

Comment: @PatrickQ But for someone that has not come across the SESSION yet, AJAX may be a step to far, for now

Comment: Thanks everybody for the right directions, always appreciate the help! Session handling seems to be exactly what I needed.